# Adding a custom format to the format drop down menu in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

How do I add a custom format to the format drop down menu in Excel 2007?  On the Home tab there is a "Number" section that has a format drop down box.  Is there a way to customize the formats in that list?

I want to quickly format the cells with commas and zero decimal places.  I can't seem to find a way to add that format to the drop down or to the quick access toolbar so it can be set with one click.

The "comma" button on the toolbar sets the accounting format which shows two decimal places.  Otherwise that would work for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a macro that does what you want (see [directions here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP100141111033.aspx#RecordMacro)).  Click on the down arrow in the Quick Access Toolbar (upper-left) and choose, More Commands.  Then in the first drop-down, choose Macros.  Then add your macro, and say ok.  Now when you click on that macro in the QAT, it will format your cell (you don't even have to have the Home Tab chosen).

When making the macro, I found that hitting the comma and then the 'less decimal places' button twice was the quickest way.